# Why does this ExtJS code get the error "this.el is null"?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to simply be able to click a button and execute some ExtJS code for testing, but this ExtJS code gives me the error `this.el is null`. **What do I have to do to get this code to work?**

**main.js:**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var button = new Ext.Button('button-div', {
        text: 'hello',
        handler: function() {
            alert('pressed');
        }
    });

    viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ button ]
    });

    viewport.doLayout();

});
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

## Working Code:

Thanks for the pointer @Mchl, it now works with this code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var button = new Ext.Button({
        text: "Click this",
        handler: function() {
            alert('pressed');
        }
    });

    var regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
        region: 'center',
        padding:'10',
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [ button ]
    });

    viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ regionContent ]
    });

    viewport.doLayout();
});
```

Comment: If you're planning on seriously diving into ExtJS I suggest you buy and use 'ExtJS in Action' by Jay Garcia. Excellent book and makes the learning curve so much gentler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a `layout: 'border'` which makes your viewport use `Ext.layout.BorderLayout`. In the documentation for this layout you'll find this note:

> - Any container using the BorderLayout **must** have a child item with
>     `region:'center'`. The child item in the
>     center region will always be resized
>     to fill the remaining space not used
>     by the other regions in the layout.